# ApplicationContextAware get ApplicationContext is null in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I build a web project with spring boot 1.5.4

And create a class implements `ApplicationContextAware`

```
@Component
public class SpringContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {


    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringContextUtils.context = context;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
```

Then I create a controller to test this class

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String test(){
        System.out.println(SpringContextUtils.getContext());));
        return "aaa";
    }
}
```

than I start the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

I visited this controller but `SpringContextUtils.getContext()` out put `null`,why? 
I am sure SpringContextUtils scaned by spring.
I know I can use `@Autowired` to get ApplicationContext,but I want to know why my program is wrong and how can I get it with ApplicationContextAware

Comment: Take a very close look at your `setApplicationContext` method... Small hint, look at the parameter and field name... Also generally when creating a thing like a `SpringContextUtils` you are doing things the wrong way, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Well I found what's wrong. I am so stupid I assigns context to itself.

Comment: @M.Deinum what would be the alternative way to `SpringContextUtils`?